# read paramerts url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a search option with 40.
If the user selects option 6 to me than just put `six=true`in the URL and send it to the search page.

In Search How do I determine which option is selected.
I need to check if all 40 variables in the URL in the URL do I determine which option is selected, there was.

Or there are other options and ways to better

in ajax or (php-asp.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you can't use `options[]=6&options[]=40` ? It will be available in **array** `$_GET['options']`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that putting six=true in the URL is what is making the parsing difficult.  Why not put `option=6` in the url instead of six=true?  Then, you can parse once for the parameter `option` and you can turn the value into a number in your code.  If multiple options can be selected, you can just have `option=6&option=3`.